# casting to base interface implementation of reimplemented interface

Tags: c#, interface, casting

I have an interface `IFace` implemented by class `Animal`. I cannot modify `IFace` or `Animal`. I want to extend `Animal` with my subclass `Human` and have it reimplement `IFace`. However, I want to be able to store an instance of `Human` in a variable of type `IFace` such that accessing that variable uses the `Animal` implementation directly—as if the variable’s type was `Animal`.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/6JjNfR

```
using System;

interface IFace
{
    void Talk();
}
class Animal : IFace
{
    public void Talk()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oink");
    }
}
class Human : Animal, IFace
{
    public new void Talk()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var human = new Human();
        human.Talk();

        var face = (IFace)human;
        face.Talk();

        var animal = (Animal)human;
        animal.Talk();

        var face2 = animal;
        face2.Talk();

        IFace face3;
        face3 = human;
        face3.Talk();

        // How to get the following to oink like animal?
        face3 = animal;
        face3.Talk();
    }
}
```

Is this possible or do I have to create a proxy class like the following?

https://dotnetfiddle.net/marXND

```
class AnimalProxy : IFace
{
    Animal Animal { get; set; }

    public AnimalProxy(Animal animal)
    {
        Animal = animal;
    }

    public void Talk()
    {
        Animal.Talk();
    }
}
```

And if the proxy is required, why is the proxy required if I can access the `Animal` implementation of `IFace` by just casting to `Animal`?

I bet the answer has something to do with how explicit interfaces work and how casting a `Human` to an `Animal` and then again casting to `IFace` *should* return `Human`’s implementation… Maybe implicit interface implementation syntax just lets the C# compiler automatically generate an explicit implementation which just calls the implicit implementation. Which means that when I cast something to `Animal` I’m accessing `Animal` methods instead of `IFace` methods even though those same methods are the “implicit” implementation of `IFace`.

So, how can I cast directly to the base implementation of a reimplemented interface—and if that’s impossible, why?

Comment: I feel obligated to point out that the idea of wanting to do this is a demonstrating that there is something severely wrong with the design of your types, and that whether its possible or not, you should *strongly* consider a re-design of your type system.

Comment: I was afraid of that, but still ;-).

Answer (score 6):

Don't have the `Human` definition re-implement the interface:

```
class Human : Animal // , IFace
{
    public new void Talk()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi");
    }
}
```

If you do that, the calling `Talk` on a `Human` will use the new implementation, but calling `Talk` on an `IFace` that happens to be a `Human` will use the base class' implementation.

See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/08/so-many-interfaces-part-two.aspx) for some more informatoin, and even weirder circumstances, surrounding interface re-implementation.

Comment: But I want to be able to pass around `Human` as an `IFace` too. I could always just have the proxy class wrap `Human` instead of `Animal` too, but that is not the point I don’t think.

Comment: @binki You *can* pass around a `Human` as an `IFace`.  If you do, and don't re-implement the interface, it will have the behavior that the base class defined for the interface.

Comment: But I want to be able to pass around the `Human` as `IFace` having overridden the interface implementation without being able to `override` it… See question: “ I want to extend `Animal` with my subclass `Human` and have it reimplement `IFace`.”

Comment: @binki Then you'll need `Human` to re-implement the interface so that any `Human` instances typed as an `IFace` will use the new implementation.  You can have one or the other, but you can't have *some* `Human` instances re-implementing the interface and some not.  Either you re-implement it, or you don't.

Comment: Sure, but why can’t I get the behavior I want if I can access the base implementation by just casting to `Animal`? Shouldn’t I be able to do something like `IFace thing = (IFace)(Animal)human;`?

Comment: @Servy - I didn't know this about the new operator, so after testing it I went looking at interface re-implementaiton in the C# spec sections 13.4.3 and 13.4.4 and didn't see this behavior described unless I misread something.  Do you know where this is defined?

Comment: @binki You can, but adding in the cast to `Animal` is superflous and cannot change the behavior.  There is no way of knowing what other variables of what other types an object was once stored in.  All you have to work with is its current compile time type and its actual runtime type.  No more.  The compile time types of previous expressions housing the same reference cannot affect the resolution of that method call.

Comment: @binki The compiler doesn't know where the `IFace` is coming from.  The cast of a cast doesn't carry forward any information. So as Servy's answer points out, that is defined on whether you put the interface in the class definition explicitly.

Comment: So there’s no way the runtime can box an `IFace` in a particular way that says it should be accessed via `Animal` when cast to `IFace`?

Comment: @SteveMitcham "Section 13.4.6 - Interface re-implementation" is the section that covers interface re-implementation.

Comment: Thanks.  That link was the 2003 language spec and didn't have that section.  I removed the link from my comment to avoid confusion. I avoid `new` in this manner like the plague so I'd never encountered this behavior